# How can a script start when I am pressing Alt+Tab keys keeping "Window Switcher Dialog" running?

Tags: scripting, xfce, window, xubuntu, dialog

I would like to know the way that when I press "Alt+Tab" keys in order to change the active window to other window, the system would recognize it and it would move the cursor to one specific place of the screen (with xdotool for example)

The mouse is sometimes inside the "Window Switcher Dialog" selecting one option of the "Window Switcher Dialog" app and at the same time this app is selecting another option. I find it confusing. When I press "Alt+Tab" keys", apart of selecting my desired application, I want to move the cursor to other part of the screen to see more clearly the Window Switcher Dialog selection. I do not know if I have explained clearly.

I am using Xfce and Xubuntu 14.04.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're going to need to describe what Window Manager (e.g. Gnome or KDE) you're using and what version before anyone can assist you with this question.

Comment: @Xalorous. Thank you. I have just edited the message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to ToZ's help I found out the way to resolve my problem.

My initial target was to move the cursor outside the WinTab window with "xdotool" command, but ToZ told me another possibility.

Here they are:
https://forum.xfce.org/viewtopic.php?id=11447